# How to find device location in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, dictionary, gps, location, jsr179

I have to find current user location in map view.How can i do that in black berry.Is it possible to find current location using GPS and show it on BlackBerry in India.Please provide some help.How can i achieve.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial on how to obtain GPS coordinates.

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11944/CS_retrieving_the_location_of_a_BB_cont_fix_962151_11.jsp

Once, you obtain the coordinates, you can open the maps application and display the location on a map.

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11944/CS_specifying_locations_on_a_map_using_location_893346_11.jsp